# Scraping a page returns no body

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to fetch contents of this url: https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region=

But it seems that the response contains no body. There is a script in the head though. This is what I have tried (added headers from the browser where this page loads fine).

```
import scrapy


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'testspider'
    headers = {
        "Host": "www.alljobs.co.il",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Referer": "https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region=",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ne;q=0.8,it;q=0.7,mt;q=0.6",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region='
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.status, 'open-board' in response.body)
```

The output is:

```
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 2.7.15+ (default, Jul  9 2019, 16:51:35) - [GCC 7.4.0], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Linux-4.15.0-20-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-19-tara
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'SPIDER_LOADER_WARN_ONLY': True}
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: eec1d23ac0e5b987
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-02-10 09:18:56 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-02-10 09:18:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region=> (referer: https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region=)
(200, False)
2020-02-10 09:18:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-02-10 09:18:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 515,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 34340,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 1.32754,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 3, 33, 57, 430553),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 53485568,
 'memusage/startup': 53485568,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 3, 33, 56, 103013)}
2020-02-10 09:18:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

With Selenium too, it seems to be the same issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/path_to_/chromedriver')
url = "https://www.alljobs.co.il/SearchResultsGuest.aspx?page=1&position=&type=&freetxt=&city=&region="
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
print("works= {}".format("open-board" in html))
```

It displays `works= False`. I am not sure why this is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first display `response.body` to see what you get - maybe you will see some warning for bots or captcha or other useful unformation.

Comment: you don't have the most important header: `USER-AGENT`. It is first header which servers check to skip bots.

Comment: @furas It is the same with USER-AGENT too. I edited the question to include it. I did display response.body in my tests. Did not include here because the script included in head is too big. The response body is like this:
`<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><script></script></head><body></body></html>`
Script is here: https://gist.github.com/santoshghimire/b5efb3ed45cd55319a36e36e706ecc6c

Comment: Since you've tested with Selenium and are apparently including the correct headers, I'm not sure that I can offer anything more to diagnose Scrapy but it might be helpful to try this [scraper via a browser extension](https://webscraper.io/). It opens a browser window and visits each URL it scrapes which means it doesn't mimic a browser, it uses your browser (complete with extensions, cookies, etc). If it works, maybe that'll be sufficient or it might at least help you narrow the issue.

Comment: it seems in `<head>` is JavaScript which loads everything but `Scrapy` can't run JavaScript - you may need `Selenium` ([scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium)) or `Splash` ([scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)) to run `scrapy` with real web browser